# Laravel 5 Apache mod_rewrite not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite

Yes there, have been similar questions, but the suggested solutions are not working for me. 
So I've set up Laravel, and the installation works fine.
Well, as long as I'm staying on the base route

```
localhost/page/
```

as soon as I'm trying to hit one of my routes, let's say

```
localhost/page/subpage
```

and the route is configured to return a view

```
Route::get('subpage', ['as' => 'subpage', 'uses' => 'GenericPageController@subpage']);
```

The method `subpage` in the Controller:

```
public function subpage()
            {

                return view('base.subpage');
            }
```

I simply get a 404 response from the server whenever i try hitting one of the routes. It doesnt matter what controller I'm using, or if its returning a view or a closure.

- mod_rewrite is enabled
- On the main directory `AllowOverride` is set
  to `All`

my `.htaccess` in the `page/public` folder looks like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Anyone has an idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.htaccess` file won't load up because it is in the `public` directory, which is really meant to be your document root. As such, you should be accessing the app by going to `localhost/page/public/subpage`.

If you want to use `localhost/page/subpage` whilst keeping your directory structure intact, then you need to add a new `.htaccess` file to the `page` directory, and **delete** the `.htaccess` file from the `public` directory.

**`/page/.htaccess` contents:**

```bsh
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /page/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Send requests to public directory...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately, due to the way in which Laravel obtains the request information, you will need to group your routes to the `page` directory in your route configuration:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'page'], function()
{
    Route::get('subpage', ['as' => 'subpage', 'uses' => 'GenericPageController@subpage']);
    // Your other routes ...
});
```

Essentially, and in my opinion, this is the easiest way to work around this. You could also move the contents of your `public` directory up one level and change the paths accordingly in the bootstrap file.

Comment: I'll try it out later, but here's another thing: I tried using the php built-in webserver, and with that its working fine?

Comment: If you run the server from the `public` directory, it will work. Is that what you did?

Comment: No, the home directory is the same as for xampp. for xampp it is working with a syntax like this: server.php/subpage... that points to an error with the .htaccess or not?

Comment: When running the PHP server, you need to run the command `$ php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` from your `page` directory. Better yet, use Homestead, or XAMPP Virtual Hosts.

Comment: Argh, I think you'Re getting me wrong here. So XAMPP home directory is (as usual) `htdocs/page` . Here the `.htaccess` or `mod_rewrite` is not working. When I'm starting the php server it is done as the following: `$ php -S localhost:8000` and the whole command is run in the directory `htdocs/page`. I don't know if the php server automatically sets the `public` directory as the home directory?

Comment: Firstly: The **document root** for `localhost` on XAMPP is `htdocs`, not `htdocs/page`. Secondly: If you choose to use the PHP server, then you will need to either run it from the `public` directory, or from the `page` directory by specifying `-t public/`. Laravel's public directory is intended to be your document root. So placing an `.htaccess` file in `page` will not help you. As such, following the guide in my answer will help you to get it working.

Comment: **However**, I recommend that you make use of a VirtualHost in XAMPP. It is much more efficient, and makes your app more portable - no config needed when moving to a production server. At the end of the day, Laravel is one of those frameworks where the `public` directory should be your document root, and everything else should be a directory below that. Using `htdocs` just gets messy.

Comment: That's a pretty good explanation, however when I was talking about `htdocs/page` it is actually set as server root via VirtualHost. Further I think you misunderstood me, `page` is just a generic name for the actual project, means a folder inside the `htdocs`. However, i changed the root directory in my VirtualHost to the `public`-directory of Laravel and I still get the same issue.